# Resubmit form with selected option

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I was wondering if it's possible to submit a form (dropdown list for the input) when the selected value `selected="selected"` is clicked. I can't seem to get it to work.

My code:

```
<form method="post" name='myform' id="box" action="javascript:alert('submitted')" onsubmit="if(this.f.value == -1){return false;}">
        <fieldset class="box_fieldset">
            <select name="f" id="f3" onchange="if(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value != -1){ document.forms['myform'].submit() }">
                <option value="-1">-- select --</option>
                <option value="1" >one</option>
                <option value="2" selected="selected" >two</option>
                <option value="3" >three</option>
            </select>
        </fieldset>
</form>
```

With the corresponding [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Q7xs/)

As you can see, it's not possible to 're-submit' `option 2` because it is already selected 
(alert doesn't get triggered).

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: make the default value something else that force the user to select something? Keep in mind that your form should submit something when something changed. There is no valid reason to re-submit in that particular case.

Comment: Why wouldn't you default it to your `-- select --` option?  That's what it's there for.

Comment: @Loïc Because I have a specific use for the dropdown list: it shows the current navigation in the website. Because there are multiple levels (depths) in the website, it's very handy for a user to go one level higher by resubmitting the selected value.

Comment: @Deryck Ignore the `"-- select --"`. I use this dropdown list to show current navigation within a multi depth website. Resubmitting the selected value is handy if the user wants to see the overview page one level higher through the dropdown list.

Comment: How bout you just do onclick (on the options)

Comment: @Deryck In this code I hardcoded the options. But in my actual implementation I softcode (generate) the options so I don't know beforehand which option gets assigned which value (or id).

Comment: @Jean-Paul if it's the current navigation in a multi depth website does it make sense to reload the current navigation if you're already there?

Comment: @Jean-Paul gotcha.  Plus, apparently `onclick` isn't recognized by `<option>` elements lol and dang that logic out of NO WHERE ladies n gentlemen

Comment: @Loic No. Look at it like this. There are 3 dropdown lists next to each other. Each dropdown list visualises a level. Hence if I want to go one level higher when I'm in the third level, I resubmit the second dropdown list.

Answer (score 0):

Well, use another event trigger.

`window.onload` should be appropriately.

[jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/calinsargan/2Q7xs/2/)

Comment: Please read the comments below the question. Refreshing isn't an option.

Answer (score 0):

when you are using onchange event you can't handle default values, like the one you chose (two);

```
<option value="-1" selected>-- select --</option>
            <option value="1" >one</option>
            <option value="2" >two</option>
            <option value="3" >three</option>
```

Comment: you can use onclick event for options

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<select id="slct">
    <option value="1" onclick="clicked(this)">one</option>
    <option value="2" onclick="clicked(this)">two</option>
    <option value="3" onclick="clicked(this)">three</option>
</select>
<script>
    function clicked(e){
        var xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xml.open("GET",""+this.value,false);
        xml.send();
    }
</script>
</body>
```

use such a trick to handle your requests